# Croatia to Poland via Germany

Tags: customs-and-immigration, transit, layovers

I'm flying from Croatia to Poland via Stuttgart. Will I need to go through immigration in Stuttgart?

I have a 1-hour layover; is that a sufficient amount of time?

Comment: Yes, immigration will be in Stuttgart.  Regarding the amount of time, it depends on whether this is a single reservation with connecting flights, or two entirely separate flights.  Which is it?

Comment: It a single reservation with connecting flights....

Answer (score 2):

Yes immigration will be in Stuttgart.

I've never flown through Stuttgart, but I've made connections in larger Schengen-area airports (Munich, Frankfurt, Vienna, Athens) with a similar amount of time, and sometimes even less.  I wouldn't worry too much about making the connection.

In any event, if you miss the connection, the airline will accommodate you on another flight.